# Adding dynamic content underneath a qt tree widget item

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm trying to implement the functionality detailed in this image, but I'm running into some trouble because it seems that tree widget items don't support this kind of content:

[image]

As you can see, I would like to be able to add dynamic content underneath a tree widget item...content such as radio buttons and sliders. Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [item delegates](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes) to implement such items properly. But I think QTreeWidget is an overkill. You should use something like [QToolBox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtoolbox.html).

Comment: Ah, being new to Qt I wasn't even familiar with QToolBox. This one seems to be much more appropriate than QTreeWidget for this use. Thank you.